# ScrollView scrolls automatically if i set text to textfield using its controller

Tags: flutter

I have created a form using scrollview widget & when initState() method _getDataUser() is called i set some prefill controllerEmail.text to textfield which makes my scrollview to scroll to the TextFormField Email source code : 
https://pastebin(dot)com/sFR7s4wS

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50713#issuecomment-693278369), you can wrap your TextField into a Focus, and only when the user has focused on the text field we set showCursor to true.

```
bool showCursor = false;

Focus(
  onFocusChange: (focus) => setState(() => showCursor = focus),
  child: TextField(
    showCursor: showCursor,
    controller: _textController,
    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
  ),
)
```

Comment: It's a hack but it solves the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is flutter's native functionality and I have programatically solved this using `ScrollController` and `Future.delayed`. Just assign your scroll view or list view to a scroll controller and do the following:

```
runZoned(() {
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0), () {
    _scrollController.jumpTo(0);
  });
}, onError: (error, stackTrace) {
  print('Zone Error: $error');
});
```